# PHP returns nothing (not even NULL)

Tags: php, function, return, boolean

I am writting a code at the moment at call this code like this:

```
$reduced = is_reduced($pid);
set_sale($pid, $reduced);
echo " - " . $reduced . " - ";
```

So, the logic behind that should be like:
I call the function `is_reduced()` to know, if a product is reduced. Normally, it should return true or false there. But I don't get anything back. You can see, I'm printing the variable with echo to the console. But I don't see anything. Not even NULL!

But on the console I can see, that it gets "is NOT reduced" gets printed out. So, it should also return someting. Because the `echo` is followed by the return command in the function `is_reduced` (Code below).

Some informations to the function:
One page can have multiple prices. This is the reason, why I have the while loop. If there is only one price, I get `-1` back on the var `aktueller_counter`. So, I jump into the first if tribe. There it is checking if there is a lower price and if yes, if this price is not 0, not "" and not lower then -1.

And as you can see, it says `echo` followed by `return`. But why do I not get any NULL or any boolean value back?

I would be very happy about help!
Kind regards!

Here the code:

```
function is_reduced($pid){
    $aktueller_counter = -1;
    while(have_rows('product_shops', $pid)): the_row();
        $aktueller_counter = $aktueller_counter + 1;
    endwhile;

    if($aktueller_counter == -1){
        $price = get_field("product_shops_0_price", $pid);
        $price_old = get_field("product_shops_0_price_old", $pid);

        if($price_old < $price) {
            if ($price_old != "") {
                if ($price_old != 0) {
                    if ($price_old > -1) {
                        $price = null;
                        $price_old = null;
                        $aktueller_counter = null;

                        echo ", is \"reduced\"";

                        return true;
                    } else {
                        $price = null;
                        $price_old = null;
                        $aktueller_counter = null;

                        echo ", is NOT \"reduced\"";

                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    $price = null;
                    $price_old = null;
                    $aktueller_counter = null;

                    echo ", is NOT \"reduced\"";

                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                $price = null;
                $price_old = null;
                $aktueller_counter = null;

                echo ", is NOT \"reduced\"";

                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $price = null;
            $price_old = null;
            $aktueller_counter = null;

            echo ", is NOT \"reduced\"";

            return false;
        }
    }else{
        for($i = 0; $i <= $aktueller_counter; $i++){
            $price = get_field("product_shops_".$i."_price", $pid);
            $price_old = get_field("product_shops_".$i."_price_old", $pid);

            if($price_old < $price){
                if($price_old != ""){
                    if($price_old != 0){
                        if($price_old > -1) {
                            $price = null;
                            $price_old = null;
                            $aktueller_counter = null;

                            echo ", is \"reduced\"";

                            return true;
                        }
                    }else {
                        $price_old = null;
                        $price = null;
                    }
                }else {
                    $price_old = null;
                    $price = null;
                }
            }else {
                $price_old = null;
                $price = null;
            }
        }


        $price = null;
        $price_old = null;
        $aktueller_counter = null;

        echo ", is NOT \"reduced\"";

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What i do when faced with one of those problems is to just write a `echo "here";` line and move it around in the code from if to next if and within a few minutes you will see how your code works (and the problem).

Comment: `Echos` in function working right?

Comment: I already did that with "is NOT reduced". So, it should be something returned...

Comment: What do you mean by "write"?

Comment: try my answer below

Answer (score 1):

When displaying boolean values to screen, you will have an easier time with, say, `var_export()` than `echo`.  It is entirely possible that your code is working properly on `false` returns (or at least some of them).

Consider these occurrences:  ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/647ff5c30629ec7d5fa426c0c0accb523bf83b62))

```
var_export(false);
    echo "\n----\n";
echo false;
    echo "\n----\n";
var_export(true);
    echo "\n----\n";
echo true;
    echo "\n----\n";
var_export(null);
    echo "\n----\n";
echo null;
    echo "\n----\n";
```

Output:

```
false
----

----
true
----
1
----
NULL
----

----
```

---

What purpose does `the_row();` have?

You can replace: `$aktueller_counter = $aktueller_counter + 1;` with `++$aktueller_count;`

<s>Instead of repeating:</s>

```
$price = null;
$price_old = null;
$aktueller_counter = null;
```

it would be DRYer to declare these values as defaults before the set of conditionals, and only overwrite them where necessary.

Since you are not returning `$price`, `$price_old`, or `$aktueller_counter` there is no reason to declare them.  They will exist only within the scope of the function.  (Unless, you have modified your code for this post and you are actually using these variables.)

Also, your conditional statements are rather verbose/numerous.  With some careful consideration, you should be able to cut down on total conditional statements and write more concise code.

Comment: I will try it with var_export :)

Answer (score 0):

Boolen Value dont get echo instead of it you can display it as string. Try this:

```
$reduced = is_reduced($pid);
set_sale($pid, $reduced);
$reduced_str = $reduced ? 'true' : 'false';
echo " - " . $reduced_str . " - ";
```